# Columns not working with ul

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to create 2 columns with an ordered list (`ul`). For some reason it's not working. I successfully created the `ul` and `li's`, but for some reason, the columns don't work. Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L2t3wo30/). And here's the code:

```css
ul {
 background-color:yellow;
 -webkit-columns:2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-columns:2; /* Firefox */
    columns:2;
}

li {
 display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
<ul>
    <li>
     first
    </li>
    <li>
     second
    </li>
    <li>
     last
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: remove style on `li`

Comment: what is the expected output, 3 columns?

Comment: @G.L.P Yes, that was the goal. When I try it: http://jsfiddle.net/L2t3wo30/2/ It only shows 2 columns. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
li {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

The `display:inline-block;` forces it to display all the `li`'s on one line.

```css
ul {
 background-color:yellow;
 -webkit-columns:3;
        -moz-columns:3;
        columns:3;
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: When I try doing 3 columns, it stays with 2. Why is that? http://jsfiddle.net/L2t3wo30/2/

Comment: IF there are only 4 `li`, then it shows only 2 lines, not three?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L2t3wo30/5/)**

```
   ul {
    background-color:yellow;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    column-rule: none;
  }
```

Then remove `column-gap` to get expected output :)

Comment: If you add a fourth `li`, then it only shows 2 columns even though I set it to 3.

Comment: IF there are only 4 li, then it shows only 2 lines, not three?